# why does rxjs observable event fire twice after timeout?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I did a little experiment to try to understand how rxjs observables work, and I'm seeing something that has me baffled...

Why does "Hello!" get logged ***twice*** after the timeout?

```
  export class AppComponent {

constructor() {
  console.clear()
  this.getObservable()
    .subscribe(data => console.log(data))
}


getObservable(): Observable<any> {
  return Observable.create(obs => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      obs.next("Hello!");
    }, 2000)
  })
}
```

}

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-observable-interval-n9coeg?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see in your stackblitz that it only fired once. The only way it could fire twice is if for some reason you had called the method twice or you are using a hot observable to emit every 2000 ms.